# Open cart, Orders not showing up in dashboard. Using paypal

Tags: paypal, opencart

Hi Im using paypal on open cart.

Followed the installation guide completely. but orders arent showing up on dash board.

I have to go Sale> Orders> Sort by Hidden and they show as cancelled.

I then manually change them to pending/complete and then it will show on dashboard

Ive checked the IPN too

All my sort orders are correctly named.

What else could i be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally happens if you're

- password protecting your website using a .htaccess/.htpasswd method
- testing locally

Basically paypal needs to access your server to send the IPN. If you're doing either of the above, then it can't. If both the above don't apply, then this can sometimes be due to paypal sandbox being slow (if you're using that rather than live PP)

Comment: .htaccess/.htpasswd  what will this page need to say? it goes in the root?

Comment: What I am saying is if you have that already your will need to disable it. Contact your host if you aren't sure

Comment: My host said all files are correctly set up, and paypal said all settings are correct on their part too

Comment: How about an SSL certificate/SSL enabled but the certificate hasn't been set up? PayPal definitely works with the current version (and all of 1.4.9 - 1.5.X)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and it helped me:

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=41841

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error for a while now. I re-uploaded the following files and it worked for me.

Sounds like your file needs updating in

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
catalog/controller/account/login.php
```

And I would also upload a fresh

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
catalog/model/account/customer.php
```